# How to slice n rows and append these at the end of dataframe by given n in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

**I have** this dataframe:

```
structure(list(id = 1:5, mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7), cyl = c(6, 
6, 4, 6, 8), n = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

     id   mpg   cyl     n
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  21       6     2
2     2  21       6     2
3     3  22.8     4     2
4     4  21.4     6     2
5     5  18.7     8     2
```

**I want to** slice row 1:n, where `n` is given in a column (here: 2), and

then I want to append these rows at the end of the dataframe.

**Desired output:**

```
id   mpg   cyl     n
<int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21       6     2
2  21       6     2
3  22.8     4     2
4  21.4     6     2
5  18.7     8     2
1  21       6     2
2  21       6     2
```

**I have tried** so far: (appends only one row!)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  bind_rows(df[1:unique(n),]) 

     id   mpg   cyl     n
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  21       6     2
2     2  21       6     2
3     3  22.8     4     2
4     4  21.4     6     2
5     5  18.7     8     2
6     1  21       6     2
Warning message:
In 1:unique(n) : numerical expression has 15 elements: only the first used
```

**I want to learn** how to put `unique(n)` in this part `df[1:unique(n),]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use `bind_rows` with `slice` - get the `first` value of 'n' convert to sequence (`seq_len`) and `slice`, then bind the data with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    slice(seq_len(first(n))) %>%
    bind_rows(df, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
     id   mpg   cyl     n
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  21       6     2
2     2  21       6     2
3     3  22.8     4     2
4     4  21.4     6     2
5     5  18.7     8     2
6     1  21       6     2
7     2  21       6     2
```

---

Or using `add_row`

```
library(tibble)
df %>% 
    add_row(!!! {.} %>% 
         slice(seq_len(first(n))))
```

---

The `unique` on `n` is applied outside the tidyverse context.  So, it should be `.$n`

```
df %>% 
    bind_rows(df[1:unique(.$n),])
```